# R ComplexHeatmap with discrete values - show missing values in legend

Tags: r, complexheatmap

I use the R package ComplexHeatmap to display my matrix with discrete values. These values range from 1-10, however, some values (e.g. 7, 8, 9) are missing. But still, I want them to be shown in the legend bar. Is this possible?

This is how far I got:

```
    library(ComplexHeatmap)
    
    discrete_mat = matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), 10, 10)
    discrete_mat[discrete_mat==7]<-NA
    discrete_mat[discrete_mat==8]<-1
    discrete_mat[discrete_mat==9]<-1

    pal <- colorRampPalette(c("skyblue", "yellow", "orange", "darkred"))(10)
    colors = structure(pal, names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

    Heatmap(discrete_mat,
        name = "Legend", 
        col = colors,
        cluster_rows = FALSE, # turn off row clustering
        cluster_columns = FALSE
        )
```

Here an image of the result:
[ComplexHeatmap where the values for 7,8,9 are missing in the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU3nE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of a work-around, but I'd just make the legend manually

*Edit:* no seed set in question so looks a bit different

```r
ht <- Heatmap(discrete_mat,
  col = colors,
  show_heatmap_legend = FALSE,
  cluster_rows = FALSE,
  cluster_columns = FALSE
)

leg <- Legend(
  title = "Legend",
  at = 1:10,
  labels = as.character(1:10),
  legend_gp = gpar(fill = pal)
)

draw(ht, heatmap_legend_list = leg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657873/23382058

```
    library(ComplexHeatmap)
    
    discrete_mat = matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), 10, 10)
    discrete_mat[discrete_mat==7]<-NA
    discrete_mat[discrete_mat==8]<-1
    discrete_mat[discrete_mat==9]<-1
    
    
    pal <- colorRampPalette(c("skyblue", "yellow", "orange", "darkred"))(10)
    #colors = structure(pal, names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
    
    Heatmap(discrete_mat,
            name = "Legend", 
            col = pal,
            cluster_rows = FALSE, # turn off row clustering
            cluster_columns = FALSE,
            
            heatmap_legend_param = list(
              #at = seq(1, 10, by = 1),  #wär gleich: at = 1:10,       
              at = 1:10,
              legend_gp = gpar(fill = 1:10, fontsize = 2),
              color_bar = "discrete"
              ),
            )
```

Comment: I thought that is the solution, and it almost is. However, it only works if the value 10 is present. In cases where e.g. the highest value is 4, all 10 values are shown in the legend, but from 4-10, all have the color of the highest value (deepred in the example)

Comment: Better to use the named vector of colors, rather than your variable `pal`, as suggested in the documentation. Gives confidence that colors are mapping correctly to values. Otherwise it is probably just pulling the first n colors from that vector as needed for the discrete values